# Cannot convert value of type [(key:string,value:int)] to specified type Dictionary<String,Int>

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following function to return sorted dictionary but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type [(key:string,value:int)] to specified type Dictionary<String,Int>
```

Here is my code:

```
func generatDictionaryFromString(str:String) -> Dictionary<String,Int>{
    var charDict = Dictionary<String,Int>()
    /* doing something here
     */
    return charDict.sorted(by:<) // <-- line with the error
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 4):

### It is Swift Type Error

Swift type of result is [(key: String, value: Int)] and function return type is Dictionary so it report error

So, It is solved by

Option :1) changing return type of function

```
func generatDictionaryFromString(str:String) -> [(key: String, value: Int)]{
    let charDict = Dictionary<String,Int>()
    /* doing something here
     */
    return charDict.sorted(by:<)    
}
```

Option :2) Changing return value.

```
func generatDictionaryFromString(str:String) -> (key: String, value: Int)? {
    let charDict = Dictionary<String,Int>()
    /* doing something here
     */
    return charDict.sorted(by:<).first   
}
```

As per your requirement you can change your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have an order, therefore they cannot have a sorted order.

Comment: @user2924482 you can sort a dictionary but the result will always be an array of key/value pairs (tuple)